# Equivalence in iOS to Javascript interface in Android?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am developing the iOS equivalent of an already running Android App. Both apps are basically a browser receiving data from a server. This includes javascript thar checks the server for changes and issues local notifications when needed. In Android this is easily done using Interfaces. Nevertheless, I cannot find an equivalent and straightforward solution for iOS (currently using Swift). Have you got any proposals on this regard? (methods or workarounds to properly do this).

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into WebKit? `WKWebView`, `WKScriptMessage` and APIs like that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Right, this seems the way to go indeed!. Thanks a lot. Found this web with a simple example to send a notification to the App from Javascript. http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift

Comment: has anyone ever found another way except the using postMessage(), calling Swift methods directly from Swift like iosListener.someMethod(), where some method for example returns a string, and iOSListener is name of userContentController, as we use it for postMessage() ?